# Смысл выражения "какая муха тебя укусила?"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "какая муха тебя укусила?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раньше считалось, что в мух могут вселяться бесы, а из них в людей, когда мухи их кусали.